# Dark theme without customisations contradicts emacs -Q

Tags: themes

I have the following in my init file.  It is supposed not to customise anything.  But it gives me a dark theme, whereas `emacs -Q` gives me a light theme.  What is going on?

This is all I have in my `.emacs` file.

```
(package-initialize)

(defun xepty-launch (&optional statck)
  "Launch xepty tools for Emacs."

  (unless (equal statck 'nogo)
    (add-to-list 'load-path
       "/home/hagbard/Opstk/xepty/")
    (load "xepty")
    (xepty-launch-tools)))

(xepty-launch 'nogo)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(savehist-additional-variables '(xepty-frame-pos))
 '(xepty-frame-pos '(34 . 34)))
```

Comment: I tend to disagree because this should not even load the package.

Comment: What does that do on its own?

Comment: After commenting out `(package-initialize)` the dark theme remains.